# Get media url in Umbraco 7 using GetProperty syntax

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I manage to get my media URL using the following syntax:

```
Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.MyImage).Url
```

But, when I try the same using the `GetProperty` syntax (strangely, I used `getProperty` for a while from examples online, but that syntax always returned some empty dynamic object), which works fine for other properties, I get all kinds of casting errors:

```
// results in:
// System.InvalidOperationException: The value of parameter 'id' must 
// be either a string or an integer

Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetProperty("myImage")).Url

// or
Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.GetProperty("_myImage")).Url
```

And using some form of `Umbraco.TypedContent<Media>` led to only more NRE and casting errors. I ultimately tried the following, but that returned an empty list always:

```
Umbraco.Media("myImage","umbracoFile")
```

I don't mind using the dynamic syntax, or any other syntax for that matter, but I am surprised that `GetProperty` apparently returns something different than the dynamic syntax.

Ultimately, all I wanted is to use the `_propName` syntax (underscore-prefixed name) to get the property of this, or any parent page, whichever is set. Short of querying the `AncestorOrSelf` list of pages, is there some way to get this to work using "simple" syntax?

**Quick update**
If I do `@CurrentPage.GetProperty("_defaultBackgroundImage")` I see the media id in the HTML, but when I try to feed it to `Umbraco.Media` I get `InvalidOperationException` *the value of parameter 'id' must be either a string or an integer*. Casting to `int` give invalid cast and using `ToString` returns the type name. There must be some way to get back the same integer value I see as when I output it using Razor `@`-syntax, right?

Comment: I've got it working with awkward syntax like `Umbraco.Media( ((Umbraco.Core.Models .IPublishedProperty) CurrentPage.GetProperty("_myImage")).Value).Url`, but this hardly seems right. Without the cast, I get an _"object does not contain a method or property 'Value'"_ error. I thought the returned object was a dynamic object, but apparently not. Still wondering if this is just me not understanding Umbraco, an oversight in the Umbraco framework, or just "by design" and I should just live with it.

Comment: Why not using `CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<int>("_myImage"))`?

Comment: @DZL: I've tried that, but whenever I used the typed syntax, I get nothing. Your code returns `0`. It appears that the underscore-syntax doesn't work with `GetPropertyValue<>`. If I remove the `_`, it works, but that is not what I am after.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value recursively? If so you can use `CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage", recursive: true, ifCannotConvert: string.Empty)`

Comment: @DZL: _that_ is what I needed, so simple (you should post it as an answer)! Yes, I needed recursiveness. The recursive feature with the `_propValue` syntax does not work with `GetPropertyValue<>`, but does work with `GetProperty`? Or is that a change in Umbraco 7? It does work with the second argument to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments above:

What you are looking for is getting the property value recursively.

Since you are using `umbraco 7` instead of accessing `CurrentPage` that is of type `dynamic` I would suggest you use strongly typed `Model.Content` property which is of type `IPublishedContent`.

Than intellisense will tell you all the methods available, one of which is:

```
Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage", recursive: true, ifCannotConvert: 0))
```

and it will work.

The same goes for `Model.Content.GetProperty` method.

Comment: Is it safe to say that the `_propValue` syntax (with added underscore for recursiveness) was (deliberately?) dropped for Umbraco 7, or never implemented (can't remember with older versions), for the typed syntax?

Comment: @Abel yes, that is correct, I am not sure when they dropped it but in ver 7 instead of underscore you should use method overload that accepts recursive as a parameter.